# Python regex to extract hashtag from within larger string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a column of social media captions. Where hashtags have been used they appear in the following format `{hashtag|\#|WorldWaterDay}`. I want to loop though this column and reformat these hashtags strings in the format `#WorldWaterDay`.

I am quite rusty on my regex. I can easily find the strings (assuming they all start and end with `{}`) using `^{.*}$`, but I am looking for an efficient use of regex to find and reformat these hashtags. I can find and split on the hashtag, remove the `|` then append the hashtag to the hashtag text in several steps, but I was hoping someone could provide some advice on a pure regex solution.

Comment: Did you try "replace" method in python? 
str='hashtag|\#|WorldWaterDay'
str.replace('hashtag|\#|', '#')
This will print #WorldWaterDay which is your desired output.

Comment: @SakshamDubey that won't remove the `}` after WorldWaterDay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a regex that will match the existing format:

```
\{hashtag\|\\#\|([^}]+)}
```

which matches:

- `\{hashtag\|\\#\|` : literally `{hashtag|\#|`
- `([^}]+)` : some number of non-`}` characters, captured in group 1
- `}` : a `}` character

You can then replace that with `#\1`. In python:

```py
df['Caption'] = df['Caption'].str.replace(r'\{hashtag\|\\#\|([^}]+)}', r'#\1', regex=True)
```